# Pass an array parameter on psql command line

Tags: arrays, postgresql, quotes, psql

I have a SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getLocationId( lng double precision[]) ...
```

which takes an array as parameter. I know how to call it from an SQL script or from PHP, but I don't know how to do it from the psql command line. I've tried constructing a string like I do in PHP:

```
select * from getLocationId("{1.0,2.0}") ...
```

but I get a parse error. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **single quotes** for the array *value*. Double quotes are for identifiers in Postgres (and standard SQL).

```
select * from getLocationId('{1.0,2.0}');
```

Alternative syntax with [`ARRAY` constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
select * from getLocationId(ARRAY[1.0,2.0]);
```